# Menu element bold when coming on page and bold another menu element on click wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, menu, bold

I've been searching a long while for the answer but haven't found a good solution.
I want the menu item DE to be bold when I enter the site and if I click on EN I want the DE to be thin again and the EN bold.

the site is : https://kxplaw.live-website.com

For now I managed to display the element with class current-menu-item in bold but that doesn't include the element when I open the page first.

I have tried things with Javascript but I'm not so sure on how to make it work.

---

Now it still doesn't work - unfortunately.
In my JS, I have the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
{ 
  jQuery(document).on("click", ".menu-language", function(){
  var lang = jQuery(this).text();
  sessionStorage.setItem("language", lang);
});
  var language = sessionStorage.getItem("language") ?? 'DE';
  if(language != null) {
  jQuery(".lang-" + language).css({"font-weight": "bold"})
} 
});
```

The problem now is that I have to click twice on DE or EN so that it becomes bold. Does anyone know what I could do in this case?
And it isn't bold on DE by default.

Comment: What did you tried in javascript? Give us your code snippet

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Appereance -> Menus`, and in upper right corner click on `Screen Options`. Then (if not checked) check option `CSS Classes`, and for every menu item now you have new field `CSS Classes (optional)` and add class `menu-language` for `EN` and for `DE`

And only for `DE` add class `lang-DE`

And only for `EN` add class `lang-EN`

And now attach on ti click event

```
// On click will add session storage language param
jQuery(document).on("click", ".menu-language", function(){
    var lang = jQuery(this).text();
    sessionStorage.setItem("language", lang);
});

// On every page load we check lang param and than we bold selected language
// Default value will be "DE"
var language = sessionStorage.getItem("language") ?? 'DE';
if(language != null) {
    jQuery(".lang-" + language).css({"font-weight": "bold"})
}
```

And now on every page selected language will be bold.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
This is what I already managed to do on the site, the EN or DE boldens when I click on them and stays. 
The problem is that I by default would like to have DE bold when the user charges the page for the first time and then be either bold in EN or DE whenever the user changes the languages. I reckon the code you wrote here is not doing that. Do you maybe have another tip for me :) ? Thank you so much!

Comment: Just add `DE` as default value for `language` variable. I updated the answer

Comment: Thank you very much! 
When I check the session-storage, it stores DEEN as one value, so it doesn't check if it's DE or EN.

Comment: It must add to that: I'm using the site editor, so I don't have the menu editor anymore. I added a class "menu-language" to the navigation DE EN and then lang-DE and lang-EN for each menu items

Comment: @Charlotte you have to update your question with code snippet that works like you described.

Comment: I updated my question :) but there is still something missing unfortunately

Comment: You add class `menu-language` on wrong element. You add on both `li` and that is ok, but you also add on `nav` tag same class [printscreen](https://prnt.sc/_l1XxjZcNXTF) You need to remove that class from `nav` element and code will work without changes.

Comment: No proble :)
You can Vote Up for my answer and mark it as Accepted answer. Thanks